# Unix timestamp to date from variable in PHP not working

Tags: php, arrays, variables, date, timestamp

I have an array of Unix timestamps. I used the following code to make a file path of the timestamps array (`$i` is used later in a loop, but at first it gets value 0 and so it's correct):

```
$date = date('d-m-y', $timestamp[$i]);
$path = $dir . '/' . $date '.csv';
```

Let's say there many timestamps in the array. If i set `$i = 0;` `$date` is a string 06-01-13 (it returns the current day, though timestamp is many weeks old), and it ignores the timestamp. But if I replace `$timestamp[$i]` with 1257426933 the output string is correct (05-11-09).

What's wrong?
My PHP version is PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Comment: Can you clarify what timestamp you are feeding and what date you are getting?

Comment: Try `var_dump( $timestamp[$i] );`

Comment: See my other comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that the $timestamp[$i] value is not what you expected?

```
var_dump($timestamp);
```

`date()` will give the current date if the second parameter is empty or not present.

Comment: Currently, array has following 6 values: var_dump($timestamp) array(6) { [0]=> int(1357426933) [1]=> int(1357430473) [2]=> int(1357434073) [3]=> int(1357437673) [4]=> int(1357441273) [5]=> int(1357498872) }

Comment: Wait a minute, there is a mess in my timestamp function, I have a look at it

Comment: Yes, of course. My fault. Timestamps were faulty as you can see. I give a wrong fromat to the function which makes them. So strtotime needs times in yyyy-mm-dd format... SOLVED